# How to do correlation Id with winston?

Tags: node.js, winston

I'm using Winston in my nodejs application.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console()
    ]
});

logger.info('What rolls down stairs');
```

I want to add to the log correlation id, but I do not want to write every time

```
 logger.info('What rolls down stairs', correlationId);
```

I want to Winston to do that. and for every log I want to get the correlationId as result of the function so I can send the correlationId to the user (not just output it to the console).

```
 const correlationId = logger.info('blabla')
```

Is it possible to do that with Winston?

Comment: Have a read here: https://medium.com/@evgeni.kisel/add-correlation-id-in-node-js-applications-fde759eed5e3. Does it help?

Comment: No, since I need to write everytime before I call to `info` this function: `const correlationId = correlator.getId();` . in the article it made by hook to response. in my question I just want to write a log and return the correlationId from the result of info function.

Comment: And sometimes I don't have express in my application. so I dont have any hook. I just want to add to the log the correlationId and return it after Winston write the log to the console/file.

Comment: [Love the nod to The Ren & Stimpy Show](https://youtu.be/5Y0dGHkAkIY)

Answer (score 1):

If this is an express app, follow the steps below.

- Setup middleware (you can install this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-correlation-id))
- In logger file, add the below code:

```js
const correlator = require('express-correlation-id');

// winston format
winston.format((info) => {
  info.correlationId = correlator.getId();
  return info;
})()
```

This is how it should look like:

```js
const winston = require('winston');
const correlator = require('express-correlation-id');

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format((info) => {
            info.correlationId = correlator.getId();
            return info;
        })(),
        winston.format.timestamp({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        }),
        winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
        winston.format.splat(),
        winston.format.json()
    ),
    exitOnError: false,
    defaultMeta: {
      // add configuration (https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)
    },
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            // for the errors (https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)
        }),
        new winston.transports.File({
            // everything else (https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score -1):

For creating `correlationId` and setup by default in Winston every log, you need to use `defaultMeta`.

```
var correlationId = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)
const winston = require('winston');
const logger = winston.createLogger({
defaultMeta: { correlationId },
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.Console()
    ]
});

logger.info('What rolls down stairs');
```

Comment: no. say I create a logger in ./logger.js
and I use `logger.info('What rolls down ..` in other file. I need to generate the correlationId every time. see my question

Comment: @JonSud, maybe this could help: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1626#issuecomment-531142958

Answer (score -2):

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export async function withCorrelationId(message:string) {
    const id = uuidv4()

    logger.info({
        message,
        id,
    });

    return id
}
```